# How to use sed delete some lines of echo output

Tags: regex, awk, sed, cut

I want to remove some lines. I already have `git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git` and I need to leave only `roi4cio-catalogs-fe`.  I used the next code but it isn't work proprely.

`echo git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git | sed -r 's/.*\///' | sed -r 's/\.+//'`

Comment: Hi Andrew, while your question seems simple. I have the feeling that we can provide you with an actual useful solution that can be used in multiple cases and might assist other users. The way your question is currently formulated, is very focussed on this single case. If you could provide us with a command/text file where you obtain the base-information from and the requested information to extract, we could setup a filter for you to assist you in this. also If you would show us some of your initial code you tried, I'm convinced we can help you out in a more satisfactory way.

Answer (score 3):

Your command does not give you the right result because you are repeating 1 or more times a dot here:

```
sed -r 's/.*\///' | sed -r 's/\.+//'
                              ^^^
```

But you want to match 1 or more characters after the dot:

```
sed -r 's/.*\///' | sed -r 's/\..+//'
                              ^^^^
```

---

To keep only the part between the last `/` till before the last occurrence of a  `.` you can use a single command with a capture group and a backreference:

```
echo git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git | 
    sed -E 's/.*\/([^/]+)\.[^./]+$/\1/'
```

Output

```
roi4cio-catalogs-fe
```

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With `awk` you could try following code. Where setting field separator(s) as `.com` OR `/` OR `.git` and printing 3rd field as per need.

```bash
echo "git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git" | 
awk -F'\\.com:|\\/|\\.git' '{print $3}'
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following solution.

```bash
echo "git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git" |
grep -oP '^.*?\/\K.*(?=\.git$)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
echo git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git |
    awk -F'[/.]' '{print $3}'
```

Using `sed`:

```
echo git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git |
    sed -E 's|.*/([^\.]+)\..*|\1|'
```

Using only `bash`:

```
IFS='/.' read _ _ var _ <<< git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git
echo "$var"
```

or using *parameter expansion*:

```
x='git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git'
x=${x%.git}
x=${x##*/}"
echo "$x"
```

Or using `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
[[ $x =~ /([^\.]+)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Using `Perl`:

```
echo git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git |
    perl -lne 'print $1 if m|/([^.]+)\.|'
```

Using `grep`:

```
echo git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git |
    grep -oP '(?<=/)([^.]+)'
```

### Ouput

```
roi4cio-catalogs-fe
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo git@gitlab.com:awg-roi-new/roi4cio-catalogs-fe.git | sed -r 's~.*/|\..*~~g'
roi4cio-catalogs-fe
```